# Replace values in a column based on conditions derived from patterns (possibly Regular expressions if needed)

Tags: python, regex, string, symbols

I have a column of home addresses that needs to be "cleaned" and pre-processed based on several patterns. For example:

[image]

I have done the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.read_csv("SampleData.csv")
df['Address'] = (df['Address'].str.split()).str.join(' ')
df.head(10)
```

Index 1, shows the address "`9 (4f7) Adam Road`". Focusing on just " `(4f7)` "
The pattern it provides is whitespace, parentheses, integer, character, parentheses, whitespace.

The output of this address should be "`9/4 Adam Road`". Hence, I need to carefully select the first integer from inside the parentheses and place it next to the first occurring integer in the address line (with a forward slash).

The second example would be, "`1 (Flat 12) Subang Heights, Slateford,`"

The output of the second example should be: "`1/12 Subang Heights, Slateford`". Here, I have to remove the word Flat and place the integer 12 next to the first occurring integer. There are occurrences of comma and symbols which needs to be removed as well.

What would be the best suggestion to go about this problem ? Should it be Regular Expressions or any other Python techniques applicable ?

Could someone with experiences in handling patterns such as this help me ?

UPDATE 1 (Data used):

```
18/8 Andy Pitt Drive
9 (4f7) Adam Road
2nd Floor, 12 China Town
1 Kuala Lumpur Park
23 KingsRoad North
81 (5F2) Prince Street
45/2 Brian's Court
1/2 Ships Corner
9/1 Eagle's Eye
1 (Flat 12) Subang Heights, Slateford,
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can capture the first number and second number in two groups and the remaining alphabetical address in third group using this regex,

```
^(\d+)\D+(\d+).*?\s+([a-zA-Z]+.*?)\W*$
```

and replace everything with `\1/\2 \3`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JNJmka/3)**

Let me know if you face any issues with any sample, I'll refine the regex as needed. It was hard to use your sample data as you posted them as image. Please avoid posting as images and post as text.

Sample Python code,

```
import re

arr = ["18/8 Andy Pitt Drive","9 (4f7) Adam Road","2nd Floor, 12 China Town","1 Kuala Lumpur Park","23 KingsRoad North","81 (5F2) Prince Street","45/2 Brian's Court","1/2 Ships Corner","9/1 Eagle's Eye","1 (Flat 12) Subang Heights, Slateford,"]

for s in arr:
 print(s, '-->', re.sub(r'^(\d+)\D+(\d+).*?\s+([a-zA-Z]+.*?)\W*$', r'\1/\2 \3', s))
```

Prints,

```
18/8 Andy Pitt Drive --> 18/8 Andy Pitt Drive
9 (4f7) Adam Road --> 9/4 Adam Road
2nd Floor, 12 China Town --> 2/12 China Town
1 Kuala Lumpur Park --> 1 Kuala Lumpur Park
23 KingsRoad North --> 23 KingsRoad North
81 (5F2) Prince Street --> 81/5 Prince Street
45/2 Brian's Court --> 45/2 Brian's Court
1/2 Ships Corner --> 1/2 Ships Corner
9/1 Eagle's Eye --> 9/1 Eagle's Eye
1 (Flat 12) Subang Heights, Slateford, --> 1/12 Subang Heights, Slateford
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks so much for this, I'm going to try your method now and I will keep you updated as I progress along. I really appreciate your support - it means a lot !

Comment: The only concern I have is, I need to push a huge csv file with a column (filled with line by line of addresses). Could we try a solution where there's one function which reads the entire csv file and then outputs processed addresses line by line ? Otherwise, I will need to copy and paste thousands of addresses into the "arr" list.

Comment: @Dinesh: Sure, try and let me know for any issues. For solution based on a function, I'll get back to you soon. Dinner call.

Comment: 1 (Flat 12) Subang Heights, Slateford, --> 1/12 Subang Heights, Slateford,          This output should have the last comma symbol removed. Some of the addresses actually have commas appearing on the front of the address such as: Flat 3, 9c Merchiston Park (to standardise everything), it'll be good to have the regex removing this front comma as well.

Comment: @Dinesh: Sorry back, had important guests waiting so had to go. Regarding removal of comma appearing at the end of any similar non-word character can be removed easily with this regex `^(\d+)\D+(\d+).*?\s+([a-zA-Z]+.*?)\W*$` Let me update the Python code in my answer.

Comment: many thanks for the update. Could you please kindly point me towards the function based solution ? Because, I have several thousands of addresses that I need to process and parse. With a function, I will be able to output line by line of "cleaned" addresses, it will be a great application to your regex code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191040/discussion-between-pushpesh-kumar-rajwanshi-and-dinesh).